# Future.then runs after build method

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future

I am trying to implement AnimatedList to my own project and it works perfectly right now. What i want to ask is how future.then runs after build method. Let me explain;

I hava below widget that i call from another widget. the part that i did not understand is init method. Widget takes a list then every row slides with animationin a specified time between them. there is 100 ms between rows animations. So far so good. But in init method looping list and create futures on top of last future. When i debug or putting some sleep method after for loop in init method(you can see below code, you can focus just init and build methods, rest of them not important), futures run after build method. it works perfectly :) but i did not get the logic here.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:guess_score/enum/match_status_enum.dart';
import 'package:guess_score/model/match.dart';
import 'package:guess_score/model/team.dart';
import 'package:guess_score/utility/utility.dart';

class CustomAnimatedList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Match> animatedList;
  final Map teamMap;

  CustomAnimatedList({this.animatedList, this.teamMap});

  @override
  _CustomAnimatedListState createState() => _CustomAnimatedListState();
}

class _CustomAnimatedListState extends State<CustomAnimatedList> {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();
  List<Match> list = <Match>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    init();
    super.initState();
  }

  init() {
    print("init");
    var future = Future(() {});
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.animatedList.length; i++) {
      print("init for i =" + i.toString());
      future = future.then((_) {
        print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.then");
        return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
          print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.delayed");
          list.add(widget.animatedList[i]);
          _listKey.currentState.insertItem(list.length - 1);
        });
      });
    }
    sleep(Duration(seconds: 5));
    print("init for ended");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedList(
      key: _listKey,
      initialItemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
        print("Build itemBuilder");
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: SlideTransition(
              position: Tween<Offset>(
                begin: const Offset(-1, 0),
                end: Offset(0, 0),
              ).animate(animation),
              child: matchRow(list[index])),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget matchRow(Match match) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            teamStat(match.competitionId, match.homeTeam),
            teamLogo(match.competitionId, match.homeTeam),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            scoreStat(match),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            teamLogo(match.competitionId, match.awayTeam),
            teamStat(match.competitionId, match.awayTeam)
          ],
        ),
        Text(matchStatusFromString(match.status).getEnumValueAsStringDesc())
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget teamStat(int league, Team team) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                widget.teamMap[league][team.id].shortName,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget scoreStat(Match match) {
    String home = Utility.getValue(match.score.homeTeamScore);
    String away = Utility.getValue(match.score.awayTeamScore);
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "$home - $away",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget teamLogo(int competitionId, Team team) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          child: SvgPicture.network(
            widget.teamMap[competitionId][team.id].crestUrl,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I think i am creating something like this? but when it will start? I dont trigger or run this future on my code.

```
future = Future(() {}).then((_) {
  print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.then");
  return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
  print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.delayed");
  list.add(widget.animatedList[i]);
  _listKey.currentState.insertItem(list.length - 1);
  });
  })
      .then((_) {
          print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.then");
          return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
          print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.delayed");
          list.add(widget.animatedList[i]);
          _listKey.currentState.insertItem(list.length - 1);
          });
          })
      .then((_) {
                print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.then");
                return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
                print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.delayed");
                list.add(widget.animatedList[i]);
                _listKey.currentState.insertItem(list.length - 1);
                });
                })
      .then((_) {
                      print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.then");
                      return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
                      print("init for i =" + i.toString() + " - future.delayed");
                      list.add(widget.animatedList[i]);
                      _listKey.currentState.insertItem(list.length - 1);
                      });
                      });
```

My second question is Is there any difference between Future.then() vs future = Future().then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Without inspecting too closely, you have not overridden `initState` properly.

[The official docs on State say:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

> If you override this, make sure your method starts with a call to super.initState().

#### With regards to your code and Futures:

- I have written a lot of useful code without ever writing `Future(() {})`.
- Does this get easier if the List-item Widgets create/own their Futures?
- Do you just want something to happen every 100ms? Try using a Timer.

Comment: Thanks. I did refactor my code and seperated as widgets. Also add a animation feature on widget. This should be the right way.